# What happens to a running rake task if I change its source?

Tags: rake, rake-task

If I am running `rake foo:bar`, if I edit the `bar` method before the task completes, will it change the task midway through?

Answer (score 0):

If you change the code of that rake task then No, if you change anything on which it depends then it will. Like changing the database schema on which task is dependent then it will change mid way

Comment: @meetalexjohnson Cause rake task once loaded in memory then it don't read the file again.